# ist [...] gegangen: why does this sentence make sense?

Tags: grammar-identification

I can't understand why the following sentence makes sense:

> Sie ist in ein fantastisches Restaurant gegangen

"ist" is the to be verb but there is also another verb "gegangen", the sentence is not in a passive form. Then how does it make sense to translate it as

> She went to a fantastic restaurant

Comment: Your translation to English is actually wrong. It should be: "She has gone to a fantastic restaurant". This translation might give you a hint.

Comment: As explained in the answer, the translation is OK

Comment: @planetmaker There are nuances between "OK" and "technically correct". With the background of this question, it makes sense to be pedantic.

Comment: @tofro agreed. But I also think it is technically correct. The usage of the tenses is different in English and German. And this is a case where it needs changing in the translation in the manner explained in the answer in the last two lines where it is explained as "typically understood". Maybe better wording would be to underline that this simple past is in fact the correct one, while the one with the past perfect is only a translation preserving word order, but not so much the temporal sense of what is expressed.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would search for this sentence in case I would be the one learning German. However, I just know that in this case the "brain work" is to search for the "verb part" *sie ist gegangen* - and I end up e.g. in this conjugation table: https://www.die-konjugation.de/verb/gehen.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Ist" isn't the main verb in this sentence, but an auxilliary verb for constructing the Perfekt tense. With a large number of verbs, the Perfekt tense is constructed with "haben" as the auxilliary verb:

> Er hat viele Sprachen gelernt.
> Ich habe das Auto in die Garage gefahren.
> Wir haben schon zu Mittag gegessen.

But [with some verbs](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfekt_im_Deutschen#Perfekt_mit_%E2%80%9Ehaben%E2%80%9C_oder_%E2%80%9Esein%E2%80%9C), "sein" is used:

> Ich bin mit einer Dampflok gefahren.
> Der Baum ist schief gewachsen.
> Sie ist schon eingeschlafen.

Technically, the use of perfect would indicate that the action was just finished, that the action continued up to the present. You might say, the person in your example sentence just came through the door of the fantastic restaurant.

But in everyday speech, the Perfekt tense is often used in place of, for example, simple past. So while a "technically correct" translation would be something like

> She has gone to/into a fantastic restaurant.

your example sentence would typically be understood as something like

> She went to a fantastic restaurant.